# Visual Studio 2017, "Mixing a dll boost library with a static runtime", when linking python_boost.lib

Tags: python, c++, boost, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to build the BGSLibrary for Windows 10, cmake 3.9, with python support, built with opencv 3.1 and boost 1.64.0 with Visual Studio Community 2017.

I built boost with python libraries (.lib) and a STATIC runtime (link=static).

```
b2 -j%cores% toolset=%msvcver% address-model=64 architecture=x86 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared --build-type=minimal stage --stagedir=stage/x64 --with-python
```

but CMAKE was having trouble finding them. It wanted something in the form of python_boost.lib. So I copied a .lib to a new folder and pointed it in PATH. See my last question.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002215/point-findboost-cmake-to-boost-python-windows-10-vs-2017/45002971#45002971](http://[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002215/point-findboost-cmake-to-boost-python-windows-10-vs-2017/45002971#45002971][1])

Now I get the much [debated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527713/mixing-a-dll-boost-library-with-a-static-runtime-is-a-really-bad-idea)

```
1>C:\Program Files\boost_1_64_0\boost/config/auto_link.hpp(370): fatal error C1189: #error:  "Mixing a dll boost library with a static runtime is a really bad idea..."
```

Can someone unpack this for me. I find it confusing.

1. The boost library is not a shared .dll, it is boost_python.lib! Mixing a dll boost library? its not a dll boost library. CMAKE clearly sees it, from Cmake output

   Boost library status:

   version: 106400

   **libraries: C:/Program Files/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib/boost_python.lib**

   include path: C:/Program Files/boost_1_64_0
2. Plus, the Visual Studio runtime is not static? When I look at the runtime, there is no static option.

[image]

Is it that I renamed the wrong .lib from boost boostrap? Here were my options (64 bit is there too, in a different folder)

Specifically, which of these files should I rename python_boost? And what should the extension be? I went back and remade with .dll support in bootstrap just in case, but cmake won't take .dll to generate. I feel like i'm missing something obviously here.

[image]

EDIT:

Visual Studio properties for libbgs, clearly trying to make a .so static library, why does it complain that its dynamic?

[image]

Comment: Please comment instead of downvote. What can I do to improve the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this error by building boost.python like

```
b2 -j%cores% toolset=%msvcver% address-model=32 architecture=x86 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static --build-type=complete stage --with-python
```