# VS LINK cannot open file 'boost_python...' instead of libboost_python3-vc140-mt-gd-1_65

Tags: python-3.x, boost

This morning I installed Python 3.6, got my b2 config to compile the boost lib and do have both flavors of `libboost_python3...` in the lib path. Then with a simple:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

I get a linker error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc140-mt-gd-1_63.lib'
```

I've searched for the likes of a flag like `USING_BOOST_PYTHON3` but every thing I read says that it should be automatic. That Boost should include the proper lib according to what I've built.

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153858/linking-against-boost-python-3-6-cant-find-boost-python-instead-of-boost-pytho) Had the same problem but never got an answer. That was as close as I could get to the links in 'Similar Questions' on the right. But I can't see how VS is part of this as boost will pick the libs.

**Update:** I just found:

```
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION == 2
#  define BOOST_LIB_NAME boost_python
#elif PY_MAJOR_VERSION == 3
#  define BOOST_LIB_NAME boost_python3
#endif
```

So now it looks like why is my major version 2 instead of 3? And even if I:

```
#define PY_MAJOR_VERSION 3
```

Right at the top of my `stdafx.h` it still links with the python 2 lib. !?

**Yet Another Update**:
So early on, and I don't have python 2.7 'installed', I had set the Additional Libraries to `C:\cpp\Python27\libs` I just set it to `C:\cpp\Python36_3\libs` and now I get:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27.lib'
```

Makes sense as boost is trying to link to 2.x instead of 3.x

Answer (score 1):

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
```

link: libboost_python3-vc140-mt-s-1_65_1.lib

Comment: Can you perhaps explain how this will solve OPs problem?

Comment: Boost.python use dynamic library default, so you should use .lib and .dll on windows, if you want to use static library, you must define macro and link static libray

Answer (score 0):

While I have all this in my head........

Boost checks with whatever python include path you are using. And why not as you may want to work with 2.7 or 3.6. So the python include must be set in `Additional Include Directories`. I had mine set to 2.7 and had forgotten, my bad. I figured it out in that `PY_MAJOR_VERSION` is Python defined.

I still had linking issues, I just wanted to link static for now, but
[Boost Python will force dynamic linking of boost, regardless of user options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31226997/3166476). But that post fixes it.

Then I still did not have a `libboost_python3-vc140-mt-sgd-1_65.lib` and I had just done a `b2 .. --build-type=complete install` to be sure. I still had the console open so I looked up the list and boost python-s was built! For what ever reason b2 created a folder, `C:\Boost\lib`, just for the staticly linked python libs. All the other libs landed in `C:\cpp\boost_1_65_0\stage\lib`

What an adventure this has been!