# boost python keeps linking python27 library

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, boost

Since days I am trying to get started with boost python on windows instead of my raspberry pi and I am facing issues with boost (or some of its dependencies) insisting on linking against `python27.lib` instead of `python36.lib` (I am using Python 3.6)

On my raspberry pi I was using the bundled python which happened to be 2.X and linked against boost_python. Now on windows I am linking against boost_python3. I checked all my include paths in CMake and they all point to the 3.6 python path. I even renamed all paths on my system that contain python (one standalone 2.7 and one in cygwin) in a different version (I renamed cygwin folder to `cygwin2` and deleted the standalone python 2.7 folder). It still wants that library...

In my program I have one single `#include` related to python and that's a `#include <boost/python.hpp>`. I followed that include in visual studio and it leads me to the python.hpp in the boost directory that I have specified in CMake, so that resolution is working. Inside `boost/python.hpp` eventually you get to `wrap_python.hpp` which includes the python headers. I also followed these in Visual Studio and it leads me to the files in the Python 3.6 folder.

Adding a comment to that include (removing it) makes the program compile fine, so I did not accidentally add it in CMake as a library. It has to be some `#pragma comment` somewhere.

So to sum up:

- There is no `#include <Python.h>` in my code
- I only include `boost/python.hpp` once
- Uncommenting that include "fixes" it
- I am using python 3.6 everywhere
- I disabled auto linking for boost in CMake with `add_definitions(... -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DBOOST_PYTHON_DEBUG)`

My question(s):

- Who or what could be causing this? Does boost directly link the python libraries?
- Is there a possibility in Visual Studio to somehow highlight all the files/lines where the preprocessor encounters a `#pragma` so I can track it down (because I am pretty sure it somehow somewhere gets a 2.7 python I am not aware of...)

Comment: Do you have boost autolinking disabled? I don't think it autolinks with the python library automatically, but it might be pulling in `boost_python` rather than `boost_python3`.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, I totally forgot to mention that, I will edit it into my question! (yes, i disabled it)

Comment: Could you perhaps create a [mcve] with a tiny source file and CMakeLists.txt that would reproduce this problem, and include them with your post?

Answer (score 0):

[I just went through this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45111866/3166476) Boost will check for `PY_MAJOR_VERSION` to determine which libs to link with. So in `c++ > General > Additional Include Directories`, add your python include path so boost can see that `PY_MAJOR_VERSION == 3`. If it doesn't it will pull the 2.x libs in by default.